# Can WCF Data Service cascade update an object down to it's children?

Tags: c#, wcf-data-services

example:

```
Parent
class Product
{
    int id {get; set;}
    string title {get; set;}
    Location loc {get; set;}
} 

Child
class Location
{
    int id {get; set;}
    int CityID {get; set;}
}
```

Can I update Product and Location, send Product to the WCF Data Service method "Update"?

The Product gets updated, but not the Child! And yes the EntityData model on the other end of the WCF Service is set up with all relations Managed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Deep update is not supported in the [OData protocol](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd541188%28v=PROT.10%29.aspx). Deep insert is supported, although not by WCF Data Services. You can batch the changes and send one payload by calling something like `context.SaveChanges(SaveChangesOptions.Batch);`, but be aware that not all services support batch and may return a 405 Method Not Allowed.